# Android - Set Alarm from TimePicker -Closed-

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, timepicker

I want to set the time with a timepicker (e.g. 10:30) and than make an alarm that makes sound 
when it's 10:30

Does anybody know how i can do this?

Or do you know a good example/ tutorial?

I hope you understand me, and i hope you could help me.

****Edit****

Found a good tutorial:
http://blog.nelsondev.net/?p=124

hope i can help somebody with it.

Answer (score -1):

Hope that this code will work for you to start alarm at 10:30.  You have to write a service `AlarmService` and write you code to play music, ringtone or whatever you want. The below code will execute the service at the specific time.

```
    // ============================
        /* Scheduling Alarm service to run at One */
        Log.i(TAG, "Alarm started");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date alarmTime = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        alarmTime.setHours(10);
        alarmTime.setMinutes(30);
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(alarmTime.getTime());

        Intent alaramService = 
            new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyAlarmService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingAlaramService = 
            PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, alaramService ,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarms.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingAlaramService );
        Log.i(TAG, "Alarm ended");
        /* End of Alarm */
```

If you want to explore [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) click on [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).